# How to generate OTA SMS for SyncML configuration

Tags: sms, over-the-air

I need to generate and send SyncML OTA SMS. I have sms provider that can send binary sms. But I'm kind of stuck in OTA spec and will be really happy if you point me to any of these:

1. An open source tool that can generate OTA sms out of some properties provided.
2. A good overview or tutorial on how to make OTA SMS (OTA spec seems not readable at all)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should not be a community wiki question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Produce following OMA-DP XML document and submit it to your Service Provider Gateway. You must strictly follow the Format for the message to be identified as configuration message by the Phone. Also contact your Service provider and ask them if they can convert an XML submission to SMS on the fly. They will need to encode the XML into WBXML and then forward the message in PDU mode.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wap-provisioningdoc>
  <characteristic type="BOOTSTRAP">
    <parm name="NAME" value="SYNCSETTINGS" />
  </characteristic>
  <characteristic type="APPLICATION">
    <parm name="APPID" value="w5" />
    <parm name="TO-NAPID" value="INTERNET" />
    <parm name="NAME" value="SYNCSETTINGS" />
    <parm name="ADDR" value="http://syncserver/sync" />
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="pb" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Contacts DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/x-vcard" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="cal" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Calendar DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/x-vcalendar" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="RESOURCE">
      <parm name="URI" value="notes" />
      <parm name="NAME" value="Notes DB" />
      <parm name="AACCEPT" value="text/plain" />
    </characteristic>
    <characteristic type="APPAUTH">
      <parm name="AAUTHNAME" value="username" />
      <parm name="AAUTHSECRET" value="password" />
    </characteristic>
  </characteristic>
</wap-provisioningdoc>
```

Here's the Function in C# to produce above mentioned XML Document.

```
public string CreateOTAXmlFile(string Username, string Password)
    {
        var ota = new XDocument(
                    new XElement("wap-provisioningdoc",
                        new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "BOOTSTRAP"),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "SYNCSETTINGS"))
                                    ),
                        new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "APPLICATION"),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "APPID"), new XAttribute("value", "w5")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "TO-NAPID"), new XAttribute("value", "INTERNET")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "SYNCSETTINGS")),
                            new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "ADDR"), new XAttribute("value", "http://syncserver/sync")),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "pb")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Contacts DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/x-vcard"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "cal")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Calendar DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/x-vcalendar"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "RESOURCE"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "URI"), new XAttribute("value", "notes")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "NAME"), new XAttribute("value", "Notes DB")),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AACCEPT"), new XAttribute("value", "text/plain"))
                                        ),
                            new XElement("characteristic", new XAttribute("type", "APPAUTH"),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AAUTHNAME"), new XAttribute("value", Username)),
                                new XElement("parm", new XAttribute("name", "AAUTHSECRET"), new XAttribute("value", Password))
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            );
        
        ota.Save(Server.MapPath("~/OTA/") + Username + ".xml");
        return (ota.ToString());

    }
```

> [PS: Believe me, this can be done via even
> a GSM modem also!]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://www.kannel.org/addons.shtml). It's pretty old but I think the [source code](https://redmine.kannel.org/projects/kannel/repository/show/trunk/gw) should show a little how to create and send OTA sms's.